# Replace strings in file with list values

Tags: python, string, file, arraylist, replace

I have  a list as :
result=[[0.0, 12.053600000000001], [0.01, 14.2272], [0.02, 15.314000000000002], [0.04, 18.5744], [0.05, -18.772000000000002], [0.67, -1.54]]

I have a file in.txt which contains values as:

```
NPTH 6
THTIM 
  0.0  0.00  0.001  -1.22
  0.01  0.123 0.550  -1.44
  0.02  0.22  0.440  -1.55
  0.04  0.456  0.220  -1.88
  0.05  0.788  0.005  1.9
  0.67  0.23  0.340   0.2

NPPD 4
1.0 5.0 8.0
1.0 4.0 2.0
2.0 5.0 2.0
4.0 5.0 2.0    

THTIM 5
2.0 1.0
1.0 2.0
1.0 1.0
```

I need to replace the second column after THTIM with second argument in each list in result list ie the string 0.00,0.123,0.22,0.456,0.788,0.23 in in.txt file need to replaced by 12.053600000000001,14.2272,15.314000000000002,18.5744,-18.772000000000002,-1.54 respectively.
ie I need my output as

```
NPTH 6
THTIM 
0.00  12.053600000000001  0.001  -1.22
0.01  14.2272             0.550  -1.44
0.02  15.314000000000002  0.440  -1.55
0.04  18.5744             0.220  -1.88
0.05  -18.772000000000002 0.005  1.9
0.67  -1.54              0.340   0.2    

NPPD 4
1.0 5.0 8.0
1.0 4.0 2.0
2.0 5.0 2.0
4.0 5.0 2.0

THTIM 5
2.0 1.0
1.0 2.0
1.0 1.0
```

What I have tried is:

```
f3=open("in.txt" ,'r')
import re
result=[[0.0, 12.053600000000001], [0.01, 14.2272], [0.02,15.314000000000002], [0.04, 18.5744], [0.05, -18.772000000000002], [0.67, -1.54]]
o2=open("out.txt" ,'w')
thtm2Cnt=0
thtm2Flag=0
for ot in f3.readlines():
    ou=ot
    print(ot)
    if re.match('NPTH',ou):

        o2.write(ou)
        strplt =ou.split()
        cnt=int(strplt[1])
    elif re.match('THTIM',ou):
        thtm2Flag=1

        o2.write(ou)
    elif thtm2Flag==1:
        if thtm2Cnt<=cnt-1:
            strplt=ou.split()
            ou = strplt[0] + "\t" +  "\t" + strplt[2] + "\t" + strplt[3] + " \n        "
            o2.write(ou)
            thtm2Cnt+=1
        elif thtm2Cnt==cnt:
            thtm2Cnt=0
            thtm2Flag=0
            o2.write(ou)
    else:
        o2.write(ou)
```

Please help with a code to achieve this.
(EDIT: import re and declare variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these with either Jupyter notebook or in Python IDE:

[image]

[image]

Comment: .It is only writing the replaced strings only on the out file. I want the whole contents of input as output and replace the second column only. I want my output as   NPTH 6 
THTIM 
0.20  12.053600000000001  0.001  -1.22
0.22  14.2272             0.550  -1.44
0.10  15.314000000000002  0.440  -1.55
0.43  18.5744             0.220  -1.88
0.34  -18.772000000000002 0.005  1.9
0.33  -1.54              0.340   0.2

NPPD 4
1.0 5.0 8.0
1.0 4.0 2.0
2.0 5.0 2.0
4.0 5.0 2.0. Please help

Comment: please help with a code to achieve the required output.

Comment: please help with a code to achieve the required output.

Comment: I have updated my requirement. Please help to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

May you want to use this?

```
import re
replace_column=["12.053600000000001", "14.2272","15.314000000000002", "18.5744", "-18.772000000000002", "-1.54"]

def process(part) :
    if re.search("NPTH \d",part) and re.search("THTIM",part):
        lines = part.split("\n")
        grid = [line.split() for line in lines[2:]]
        result = []
        for idx, row in enumerate(grid):
            newrow = []
            for index, cell in enumerate(row):
                if index == 1:
                    newrow = newrow + [replace_column[idx]]
                else:
                    newrow = newrow + [cell]
            result = result + [newrow]
        return "\n".join(lines[:2] + ["\t".join(row) for row in result])
    else:
        return part

fr=open('in.txt','r')
fw=open('out.txt','w')
f = fr.read()
fr.close()
parts = f.split("\n\n")
fw.write("\n\n".join([process(part) for part in parts]))
```

Comment: I have updated my requirements. I need to change the value for first thtim block only Please help to fix this

Comment: .It is not updating the value .Please help with a code to achieve the required output as mentioned above.

Comment: cant write mapping as it should automatically take values from file. Cant assign to it. Is there any other method to achieve this.

Comment: .Is there any other way without mapping as mapping={0.0: 12.053600000000001, 0.01: 14.2272,0.02: 15.314000000000002,0.04: 18.5744,0.05: -18.772000000000002,0.67: -1.54}. this should automatically read from file and map.Please help to achieve this.

Comment: You can use a switch. Can you explain better the mapping? You use a file for mapping?

Comment: I have updated my requirement .Please help to fix this @Gonzalo De Benito Cassadó

Comment: try with mapping = {0.00:12.053600000000001,0.123:14.2272, 0.22 :  15.314000000000002,0.456 : 18.5744,0.788 : -18.772000000000002,0.23 : -1.54 }

Comment: @ Gonzalo De Benito Cassadó I dont need mapping in this program as i have directly take values from the file. Mapping will be a problem if any change in the file

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you if you don't explain better your problem/question. Best regards

Comment: @ Gonzalo De Benito Cassadó. My text file contains more data that i mentioned only certain data in the requirement. This code is not working.I have mentioned only a piece of data in the file, as it contains more data. This code is not working for me. Can you look at my code and edit to fix this.

Comment: For me it's working .Otherwise I wouldn't post the solution

Comment: @ Gonzalo De Benito Cassadó .Thank you for the code